# Android image display full height - loaded asynchronously

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view, universal-image-loader

Hey I begin my adventure with Android and I can't solve one problem.
I am loading pictures from web server using Universal Image Loader. I put them into Relative Layouts which is located in ListView. The effect that I want to achieve, is that pictures are displayed on the entire screen with full width and height with a small box at the bottom. 
In the IDE preview, everything looks ok:
[image: android image view]

But on my phone loaded images look like that. I want them to be displayed with full height. It is necessary to use programming functions to achive it?

[image]

Loading images:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(
                wallpapers.get(position).getSrcUrl()//the drawable
                , currentWallpaperViewHolder.imageViewWallpaper//the image view
                , imageLoaderOptions);//the display options

return itemView;
```

List view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/WallpapersListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Image view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaper_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaper_date_for_use"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Date of use" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have a RelativeLayout as your root view.  Try wrapping the outside RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout.

Comment: My root view is LinearLayout. Sorry if this is not clearly :) In LinearLayout I have ListView, with collection of RelativeLayouts

Comment: This is the entire code. The code is divided into two views - ListView and RelativeLayout to display images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

1. Get the device height.
2. And then set imageView height programatically as the device height.

Comment: I know I can do it programmatically. As someone who is starting an adventure with Android I would like to know if it can be done using only the parameters of view?

Comment: Then you can use LinearLayout surrounded with ScrollView rathar than using ListView. It will solve your problem. Then adding each LinearLayout programatically.

Comment: So I tried your solution but the effect is the same.